# c# separate string into different cells in csv file

Tags: c#, .net, csv

How to separate each line into different cells? I get the lines of information separated with comma yet I want to separate them likewise.

```
        string path = @"..\Debug\data\IrisData.csv";
        var content = File.ReadAllText(path);

        var contentLines = content.Split('\n');
        var csv = from line in contentLines
                  select line.Split(',').ToArray();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            foreach (var data in csv)
            {
                foreach (var cell in data)
                {
                    var newline = string.Format("{0}", cell);
                    newline = cell != data[4] ? newline + "," : newline;
                    sw.Write(newline);
                }
                sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Did you get any error or Is your code have different output then expected.

Comment: I get lines of information e.g. "sepal_l,sepal_w,petal_l,petal_w,species" instead of column separated data like: "sepal_l", "sepal_w", "petal_l", "petal_w", "species"

Comment: You should try to split this way: `string[] contentLines = content.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` Splitting on `\n` could leave some `\r`, messing with your columns.

Comment: `var newline = string.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, cell);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
newline = cell != data[4] ? "\"" + newline + "\"," : newline;
```

May this helps you

Comment: Whats is the output now ??

Answer (score 1):

`";"` separates data to different cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem.

Are you trying to separate the csv and put it together again? At least that's what your code looks like for me..

I don't like using `var` for every variable, since it can lead to mistakes or unintended behaviour. I think that happened to you as well.

`String.Split(char)` returns a `string[]`

```
        foreach (var data in csv) // csv is a string[] -> data is a string
        {
            // data is a string which is basically a char[] -> cell is a char
            // I don't think, that's what you wanted...
            foreach (var cell in data) 
            {
                var newline = string.Format("{0}", cell);
                newline = cell != data[4] ? newline + "," : newline;
                sw.Write(newline);
            }
            sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Maybe you can tell me, what you actually wanted to do, so I can help you with that :)

Comment: I've got a line of information in my csv file : sepal_l,sepal_w,petal_l,petal_w,species
I want to put each data, which is seapareated by coma, into a different column.

Comment: Well, than I think `csv` already contains your data..

You could access it by `csv[lineNumber, columnNumber]`.

Comment: Yes, it does but I cannot write it to a csv file. Every next cell is being appended to the former one which means I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at TextFieldParser:

Make sure to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic Assembly, and add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`

```
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"..\Debug\data\IrisData.csv"))
        {
            parser.SetDelimiters(new String[] { "," });

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();


                // fields will contain every seperated cell

            }

        }
```